# Why am i getting memory allocation error?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I've successfully connected to MySQL database through MySQL Connector/ODBC, please see the image below.

[image: MySQL Connector/ODBC]

Also I've successfully created SQL Server 2005 "Linked Server to MySQL".

Unfortunately i am getting "Memory Allocation Error", as shown in image below. I am unable to identify the cause of it.

[image: Memory Allocation Error]

Comment: Is it this *specific* query that has the issue, or do all queries have the problem? I.e. if you just do a simple select, does that also get the memory allocation error?

Comment: Not all queries have the problem, i am getting this error in this specific query and update/insert query in general. 
Select query is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SSIS with MySQL:

- http://dbperf.wordpress.com/2010/07/23/sql-server-integration-services-2008-ssis-and-mysql/
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/03/04/connecting-to-mysql-from-ssis.aspx
- http://sqlmag.com/business-intelligence/integrate-mysql-and-sql-server
- http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/06/04/howto-connect-to-mysql-in-ssis/